# Django survey with forms

Tags: python, django, forms

I am building a survey tool and I'm wondering how would I continue with this or if my current solution is even the proper way to do it.

1. Admin of the page may add or remove questions from questionnaires, so if I have understood it, I can't use ModelForms to handle the form data?
2. A form may consist of 5 multichoice questions and 2 free text questions or any other amount of different types of questions so there isn't any fixed type of questionnaire
3. How do I then save the values of the form as I do not have a model to use?

Is this even possible to achieve without using a model for the form?

Thank you for any input in advance.

---

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Questionnaire, Question, Answer

def index(request):
    all_questionnaires = Questionnaire.objects.all()
    all_questions = Question.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'questions/index.html', locals())

def questionnaire_detail(request, questionnaire_id):
    questionnaire = Questionnaire.objects.get(id=questionnaire_id)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(questionnaire=questionnaire)
    return render(request, 'questions/questionnaire.html',
                  {'questionnaire': questionnaire, 'questions': questions})

def calculate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

MC = 'MC'
CN = 'CN'
TX = 'TX'

CATEGORY = (
    (MC, 'Multichoice'),
    (CN, 'Choose N'),
    (TX, 'Text'),
)

VALYK = '1'
VALKA = '2'
VALKO = '3'
VALNE = '4'
VALVI = '5'

MULTICHOICE = (
    (VALYK, 'Least'),
    (VALKA, 'Less than average'),
    (VALKO, 'Average'),
    (VALNE, 'More than average'),
    (VALVI, 'Most'),
)

class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    questionnaire_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                          verbose_name="Questionnaire",
                                          null=False,
                                          default=None,
                                          blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.questionnaire_name

class Question(models.Model):
    questionnaire = models.ManyToManyField(Questionnaire)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                                     verbose_name="Questionnaire name",
                                     null=True,
                                     default=None,
                                     blank=True)
    question_category = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                         verbose_name="Question category",
                                         null=False,
                                         choices=CATEGORY,
                                         default=None,
                                         blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)

class MultiChoiceAnswer(Answer):
    answer = models.IntegerField(choices=MULTICHOICE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```

**questionnaire.html**

```
{% extends "questions/base.html" %}
{% block title_html %}
    Questionnaire
{% endblock %}
{% block h1 %}
    Questionnaire
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% if questions|length > 0 %}
        <form action="{% url "questions:calculate" %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for question in questions %}
                {{ question.question_text }}<br>                
                {% if question.question_category == "MC" %}
                    <input type="radio" name="{{ question.id }}" value="1"> 1<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="{{ question.id }}" value="2"> 2<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="{{ question.id }}" value="3"> 3<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="{{ question.id }}" value="4"> 4<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="{{ question.id }}" value="5"> 5<br>
                {% elif question.question_category == "CN" %}
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ question.id }}" value="a">a<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ question.id }}" value="b">b<br>
                {% elif question.question_category == "TX" %}
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="{{ question.id }}">Test</textarea><br>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}    
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>                 
    {% else %}
    <span>No questions</span>
    {% endif %}             
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You should definitely use the built in Django forms. I can't see a reason why you can't use a model form.

Comment: Hmm, It seems then that I have misunderstood model forms and forms in general badly. Back to reading then, thank you.

Comment: Yes, I've never had the need to create the form manually like you did above. If the fields the user must fill in matches your model, then you should use a model form. If not, you should still use a normal Form class. Also take a look at modelformsets and inline model formsets in case you need to save multiple model instances that's attached to a main parent model

Comment: @GeeS Can you please add an example answer/solution what you used in the end here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up with. Edited it a bit to be more generic.

In the view there is checking if the form was loaded or submitted. If it was submitted, then check the validity of all of the forms. As there are multiple forms they are then made as formsets.

View

```
def answerpage(request, questionnaire_pk):
    AnswerFormSet = formset_factory(AnswerForm, extra=0)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(questionnaire=questionnaire_pk)
    qname = Questionnaire.objects.get(id=questionnaire_pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        answer_formset = AnswerFormSet(request.POST)
        if answer_formset.is_valid():
            for answer_form in answer_formset:
                if answer_form.is_valid():
                    instance = answer_form.save(commit=False)
                    instance.fieldValue = answer_form.cleaned_data.get('fieldValue')
                    instance.save()
            return redirect('main:calcs')
        else:
            return redirect('main:home')
    else:
        quest_id = request.session.get('questionnaire_key', defaultValue)
        question_data = [{'question': question,
                          'questionnaire_key': quest_id} for question in questions]
        answer_formset = AnswerFormSet(initial=question_data)

    combined = zip(questions, answer_formset)
    context = {
        'combined': combined,
        'answer_formset': answer_formset,
        'qname': qname,
    }
    return render(request, 'main/questionnaire.html', context)
```

The form is a modelform with the default widgets overwritten.

Form

```
class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = QuestionAnswer
        exclude = ['']
        widgets = {
            'field1': RadioSelect(choices=CHOICES, attrs={'required': 'True'}),
            'field2': HiddenInput,
            }
```

Webpage renders the values from the view in to a table. Management_form is needed to handle the formset values correctly.

Webpage

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/survey.css' %}">
<h1>{{ qname.questionnaire_text }}</h1>
<h2>{{ qname.description }}</h2>

<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ answer_formset.management_form }}
    <table>
        {% for question, form in combined %}
            <tr><td style="width:65%">{{ question }}{{ question.question_type }}</td><td style="width:35%">{{ form.business_id }}{{ form.question }}{{ form.questionnaire_key }}{{ form.answer_text }}</td></tr>

        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <div class="buttonHolder">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" id="next_button"/>
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```